# Negative binomial distribution - subtraction of two variables

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ is the count of products that come from assembly line before 3 defect ones came, and $Y$ is the count of products from the same line before 4 defects. The probability of a product to be defective is constantly $p$. Define $X\sim NB(3,p)$ and $Y\sim NB(4,p)$. If we subtract $Y-X$, I can write: $X - Y \sim NB(4-3,p)$

Now I think that $Y-X$ is a geometric distribution, because we care about the first defect only. Here I am not sure whether there is a catch with dependent variables or not. Or maybe I am right?

Comment: Is Y the count of products after $4$ defects, or before?  The question says after, but that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I think that X and Y are independent. Yes, let me fix it. It should be before.

Comment: They're not independent.  If $X$ is unusually large, so will $Y$ be.  But you need them to be independent.  You mean $Y-X$ though, not $X-Y$.  We always have $Y\geq X$.  (I'm assuming that when you say $Y$  is the count of products, you mean successful products.)

Comment: Yes, my bad. It's Y-X. I'm a little bit sick today, so sorry about that.

Comment: No need to apologize.  Get well.

Comment: Thank you!  But I am still confused about my way of solving this problem and where I am wrong.

Comment: Why do you think you are wrong?  Isn't $NB(1,p)$ the same as a geometric distribution?

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is a geometric distribution. But the problem seemed a bit easy to me, so I thought there is something I am missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ is the number of successes before $3$ defects, and $Y$ is the number of successes from the same line before $4$ defects, we can say that $Y-X$ is the number of successes after the third defect up to the fourth defect. This is $\text{NegativeBinomial}(1, p)$ or a geometric distribution with probability $p$. Indeed we are counting the number of successes until the first failure, ignoring whatever number of successes/failures we had before.